# What's the best way to provide localization for PHP?

Tags: php, localization

I think Wordpress uses .mo files. What does this mean? Why?

Comment: Please do research before asking questions.

Comment: @Gordon, it was just one example. I would like to know other methods.

Comment: well, even then: please do [research](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=localization+php) before asking. Then come up with a concrete question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 2):

[Wordpress uses](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html) method of providing localized translations. This is a pretty common method, with [support built in into PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) and many tools (such as [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)) are available to aid translators in working with this format.

Using this method usual means your translatable natural language is wrapped inside a _() function call, making it easy to extract for translation tools.

Answer (score 2):

.mo files are gettext standard message files. I suggest you a thorough read of http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php and other sources you can easily find googling about **gettext**.